# Sum an entire (changing) Object using d3

Tags: jquery, d3.js

If I have an object containing 20 keys, and over 3000 entries, is there a way using d3 to SUM the entire object?

For example if I have:

```
Country: Germany, val2007:9.3, val2008:8.6
Country: Germany,val2007:3.4, val2008:1.0
Country: Austria, val2007:23.0, val2008:9.2
Country: Austria, val2007:1.2, val2007:3.2
```

Can I produce an array as the following?

```
Country: Germany,val2007:12.7, val2008:9.6
Country: Austria, val2007:24.2, val2008:12.4
```

Bearing in mind that I won't know the key names all the time and the 'val' fields could be anything from val2007 and val2008 to val1997 -> val2017

Answer (score 3, accepted):

D3 doesn't provide a simple way to do this, but it offers several tools that are useful. The first is `d3.nest` ([docs](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays#wiki-d3_nest)), which can group rows on specific keys. After that, you need to figure out how to sum the rows for, say, Germany yourself - here I use `Array#reduce`, which I think works well for this sort of problem:

```
function rollup(rows) {
    return rows.reduce(function(agg, row) {
        // you could pre-calculate this if all rows had the same keys
        d3.keys(row)
            .filter(function(k) { return k !== 'Country' })
            .forEach(function(k) {
                if (!(k in agg)) agg[k] = 0;
                agg[k] += row[k];
            });
        return agg
    }, {});
}

data = d3.nest()
    .key(function(d) { return d.Country; })
    .rollup(rollup)
    .entries(data)
    .map(function(entry) {
        entry.values.Country = entry.key;
        return entry.values;
    });
```

You can see the working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/nrabinowitz/MB3yz/

Comment: That's an awesome example, and I'm quite pleased I understand it, thanks for that, certainly helped a lot!!